# BigQuery for Spring batch metadata

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch

Anyone used BigQuery to store spring batch jobs, steps and execution instead of other RDBMS? Trying to build a spring-boot batch application to read from BQ table and write it to a pubsub. So thought of using the same BQ to store jobs metadata. Any help is appreciated?

Answer (score 1):

For code samples, take a look at [the relevant snippets on Google's GitHub](https://github.com/googleapis/java-bigquery/blob/0ffbac349cc27ce72b06e05723e45a973b69cef1/samples/snippets/src/main/java/com/example/bigquery/QueryBatch.java).

Before trying this sample, follow [the Java setup instructions in the BigQuery QuickStart using client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-client-libraries).

For more information, see [the BigQuery Java API reference documentation](https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-cloud-bigquery/latest/overview).

To authenticate to BigQuery, set up the Application Default Credentials. For more information, see [Set up authentication for a local development environment](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/provide-credentials-adc#local-dev).

Comment: Thanks for replying @senthil. But my question is how we can integrate spring batch schema with BigQuery?